# how can I setup git server with permission control using ssh key?

Tags: networking, server, permissions, ssh, git

I tried running git server with ssh key control but it doesn't work.  For my personal git usage, I have no problem setting up git server and using it alone. Now, to operate a git server with permission control using ssh key(so that some permitted people can access the git server), I treid this.

1. in machine A (at `my.server.ip.addr`), I made a repository `/home1/repos_test/nnn.git` using account `prjgit`. `prjgit` is in `sudo` group and I changed the owner and group of the `nnn.git` directory to `prjgit`.
2. I made another account on machine B and I generated ssh key `ssh-keygen -C "mike@my.comapny"` and pasted the content of `id_rsa.pub` in machine A's account `prjgit`'s `.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

But when I try to git pull by `git pull ssh://prjgit@my.server.ip.addr/home1/repos_test/nnn.git`, it asks me to enter password with this prompt `prjgit@my.server.ip.addr's password:` and the only way I can enter and git pull is to enter the `prjgit`'s "account" password. This is not I wanted. I wanted mike to enter without password, or to enter with `mike`'s own password. What am I doing wrong?

### ADD

on @muru's suggestion I tried connecting with `ssh -v ...` and the last part looks like this. The public key method doesn't seem to work out and it goes into password method.

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/mthompson/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:6x3bHdxx1uTZSIRupFE3Lh+9b0Y4epRb7Lbx+3veT4w
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mthompson/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mthompson/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mthompson/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mthompson/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mthompson/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mthompson/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
prjgit@129.254.30.90's password:
```

I pasted my id_rsa.pub in the server's authorized_keys file. But why wouldn't it work out?

Comment: Have you checked the logs of sshd on A to see what exactly happened when you tried to do `git pull ssh...`? Also, try connecting using plain SSH to get some debug logs (`ssh -v prjgit@my.server.ip.addr`)

Comment: Thanks, I added the ssh -v result. and how can I check the sshd log on server side? I checked /var/log directory but couldn't find one (CentOS 6.9).

Comment: Oh, I found the sshd log (/var/log/secure) and it says: Apr 13 15:22:07 localhost sshd[7133]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for file /home/prjgit/.ssh/authorized_keys.  I tried changing the mode to 0x777 in vain.

Comment: Maybe there's a `/var/log/auth.log`? The permissions on the `.ssh` directory or `.ssh/authorized_fkeys` file might not be correct (e.g., maybe they're group-writable or something, but SSH wants them to be writable only by the user). Maybe try adding using `ssh-copy-id` instead of manually copy-pasting.

Comment: `0x777` is the *opposite* of what it should be. The file and directory should be writable only by the user. Private keys should be readable only by the user.

Comment: @muru right! the directory .ssh 's permission was wrong. so I changed to `drwx------` and now it works! Thanks alot as usual :)  If you could take some time to put an answer, I'll selcted it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSH has security requirements for the `.ssh` directory, `authorized_keys` file and keys.

- All of these should be writable only by the user. If they're writable by others, ssh will ignore them, so a world-writable `.ssh` would mean `authorized_keys` and other files in that directory are ignored by the server.
- Private keys (on the client) should be readable only by the user, or the client won't try them for authentication.

Comment: Thank s a lot. BTW, I found, using yet another account in machine B, if I enter `prjgit`'s account password, I can clone the git even if I didn't send the id_rsa.pub file to the server. It wouldn't be a problem because it's still password protected..